# Apache Geode - Unable to download binary

Tags: apache, download, binary, geode

I am unable to download Apache Geode, Binary, from all the 3 sites mentioned. Pls help.

http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/incubator/geode/1.0.0-incubating.M2/apache-geode-1.0.0-incubating.M2.zip

http://www-us.apache.org/dist/incubator/geode/1.0.0-incubating.M2/apache-geode-1.0.0-incubating.M2.zip

http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/incubator/geode/1.0.0-incubating.M2/apache-geode-1.0.0-incubating.M2.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to download from the links you posted, can you try again?

Comment: Thanks @Swapnil. I faced a strange issue, while downloading via the proxy server. It would just download a 16kb file.